# How are quadratic inequalities and absolute value equations related?

Tags: inequality, quadratics, absolute-value

$$|x+2|+|x-3|=5$$  and

$(x^2-x-6)\leq0$

Have the same real solution of $[-2,3]$

I was wondering if there was a formula to convert from one to the other, such as taking a quadratic inequality and turning it into an absolute values equation. I know it's not very practical as the method for solving both formats is similar, but I was wondering about the relationship between the formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|x-a|+|x-b|=|a-b|\Leftrightarrow(x-a)(x-b)\leq0$$

You can use even the following equation $$\sqrt{x-x^2}=\sqrt{x-x^2},$$
which gives $[0,1]$.

Also, the equation $$\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$$ is an equation of the disc.

Also, $$|x+y|+|x-y|=2$$ is an equation of the square.

Comment: @Tom Rowaway Because the domain gives $x-x^2\geq0$ or $0\leq x\leq1$.